# I'd like to see answers deleted by "not me" on SO - how?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation

Some time ago, an answer of mine was deleted, with no explanation, by a moderator.

It seems to have gone past the "My profile" -> "All actions" -> "Answers" -> "Recently deleted answers" stage, but it is still niggling me that a demonstrably-correct answer was deleted. At the time I thought "meh," but now I think I should hold moderators to higher standards than not giving a reason.

How can I see my previous answer to raise my grievance?

(And you lot know what I'm like and I could be totally mistaken, so no links here until I've got some way to read the answer I can't currently see.)

Comment: You are almost certainly talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454181), as it is the only deleted answer of yours that qualifies *except that the moderator that deleted it was **not** just elected*. It was a link-only answer and justifiably deleted. (The other mod-deleted answers were deleted 7 or more years ago).

Comment: Note that the blue banner with the deletion notice [links to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), explaining why answers such as yours are deleted: *This includes answers that are: [...] barely more than a link to an external site*. We generally do not provide further explanation when that article covers the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a member of the 10k club you can run a search for all of your deleted posts (regardless of by whom they were deleted). As the [description of the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says

> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

So a search query to that effect is simply

```
deleted:1
```

And it will present all of your deleted post history (as is limited to regular users).

Comment: Does "own deleted" posts mean "own-deleted" posts? I am not seeing my-answer which was deleted by a moderator. I see a message "Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content," so maybe I don't own content which is deleted.

Comment: @AndrewMorton If you posted it, you're the owner and should be able to see it regardless of who deleted it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Ah, no. Content you own is content you posted. It may be licensed under CC-BY-SA, but the copyright is still yours, you *own* it as it were. I checked my own history and saw a couple of posts I didn't delete myself. Try improving the search, perhaps? Here's a reference of all the search operators https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have posted *much* deletion-worthy-after-or-even-before-further-consideration material, and whomsoever clears it up where I fail to is worthy of commendation, but, try as I might, I can't find the answer I provided which was deleted.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Can I filter actions by who did them on my posts, if, say, I knew who did the action?

Comment: @Andrew - Not that I'm aware. But you can filter by the approximate time of the deletion, since you say you know what that is. Just enter a `lastactive` filter with the date range you recall.

Comment: This is the answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454181. It was a link-only answer, I’d have deleted it too had I handled the flag.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Deletion time isn’t indexed; last active is the last edit time, not the deletion time. I simply searched for deleted answers for Andrew (`user:1115360 is:a deleted:yes`) then checked them all.

Comment: @Martijn Based on the OP's description, I don't think that answer is the one (as it wasn't deleted by a moderator who was elected in _"the last round of mod elections at the time of this post"_). If that's the case, the OP may look for it using the same search query.

Comment: @41686d6564 it is the *only* post of theirs that was recently deleted by a moderator. The other such posts were deleted 7 or more years ago. The moderator that deleted the answer linked here was, at that time, *relatively* new, but I think Andrew simply got Jean-François mixed up with the newly elected moderators. I am 99.9% certain this is the alleged post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that would be the post. Thank you for finding it. I didn't think it was a link-only answer, just that it had links to the documentation of methods which would have accomplished what the OP wanted. Maybe there's not enough of a distinction there.